# How to make raster tiles in Albers projection or Equidistant Conic?

Tags: leaflet, raster, proj

It`s necessary to make tiles in the non-mercator projection to display them in Leaflet using the Proj4Leaflet library.
How can i do this?

I tried to do it in Qgis, but the result was negative.

Comment: In R you can use `terra::project` and  `terra::makeTiles`

Comment: Is there a way without R?

Comment: of course, but this is a coding site. Perhaps ask this at https://gis.stackexchange.com/.